# Trouble with output for Fantasy Game Inventory

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm a beginner working on the Automate the boring stuff with Python book. I'm stuck on this practice problem. The instructions are as follows:

List to Dictionary Function for Fantasy Game Inventory:

Imagine that a vanquished dragon’s loot is represented as a list of strings
like this:

```
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
```

Write a function named `addToInventory(inventory, addedItems)`, where the
inventory parameter is a dictionary representing the player’s inventory (like
in the previous project) and the `addedItems` parameter is a list like `dragonLoot`. The `addToInventory()` function should return a dictionary that represents the updated inventory. Note that the `addedItems` list can contain multiples of the same item. Your code could look something like this:

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):


    inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
    dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
    inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
    displayInventory(inv)
```

The previous program (with your `displayInventory()` function from the
previous project) would output the following:

```
Inventory:
45 gold coin
1 rope
1 ruby
1 dagger
Total number of items: 48
```

My code is as follows

```
    def addtoinventory(inventory,lootlist):
    for i in range(len(lootlist)):
        if lootlist[i] in inventory:
            inventory[lootlist[i]] = inventory[lootlist[i]] + 1

    else:
        inventory.setdefault(lootlist[i],1)

        return inventory


def displayinventory(inventory):
    total_items = 0

    for k,v in inventory.items():
        print(k + ' : ' + str(v))

        total_items = total_items + v

    print("Total number of items: " + str(total_items))


    inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
    dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
    inv = addtoinventory(inv, dragonLoot)
    displayinventory(inv)
```

My output is like this:

```
gold coin : 45
ruby : 1
rope : 1
Total number of items: 47
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've fully indented the code block which contained `def addtoinventory(inventory,lootlist):` and `def displayinventory(inventory):`, because `def displayinventory(inventory):` was formatted as outside a code block. I maintained the relative indenting, but you should double check the indentation in that section of your question to verify it's actually was is in your code (even though this is from a year ago). It's possible that those were intended as two separate code blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your indent of `else:` is wrong. You should use if-else, but your code is for-else. The code below works well.

```
def addtoinventory(inventory,lootlist):
    for i in range(len(lootlist)):
        if lootlist[i] in inventory:
            inventory[lootlist[i]] = inventory[lootlist[i]] + 1
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(lootlist[i],1)
    return inventory
```

The result is below.

```
>>> inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
>>> dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
>>> inv = addtoinventory(inv, dragonLoot)
>>> inv
{'gold coin': 45, 'rope': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'ruby': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and it worked just fine for me, apart from the items and their numbers being in the wrong order, which is easily fixed if you change the print line to this:

```
print(str(v)+' : '+k)
```

Comment: Well spotted! This is because the edits mu made in OP's question fixed the issue. I've raised a mod flag for rollback request of the edit. Otherwise It makes no sense to have this question here and all answers are in vane.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. I wasn't able to get rid of the brackets though, and for some reason the pprint didn't work. But this code serves the purpose anyway...

```
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']  

#Turn dragonLoot list in to a dictionary:
list={}
for i in dragonLoot:
    if i not in list:
        list.setdefault(i, 1)
    elif i in list:
        list[i] = list[i] +1

#Merge dictionaries:
for i, v in list.items():
    if i not in inv:
        inv.setdefault(i, 1)
    elif i in inv:
            inv[i]=inv[i]+v

import pprint

print('Inventory: ')
pprint.pprint(inv, width=1)
print('')
total=0

#Count the total number of items:
for i, v in inv.items():
    total=total+v

print('Total number of items: ' + str(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        item_total += v
        print(str(v) + ' ' + str(k))
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

def addToInventory(inventory, addItems):
    for k in range(len(addItems)):
        inventory.setdefault(addItems[k], 0)
        inventory[addItems[k]] += 1
    return(inventory)

inventory = {'rope': 1, 'torches': 6, 'gold coins': 42, 'daggers': 28, 'arrows': 12, 'knives': 50}
dragonLoot = ['gold coins', 'daggers', 'gold coins', 'gold coins', 'ruby']
updatedInventory = addToInventory(inventory, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(updatedInventory)
print("Inventory updated.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
def addToInventory(dragonLoot,inv):
    count={}
    for item in dragonLoot:
        count.setdefault(item,0)
        count[item]=count[item]+1

    for k in count.keys():
        if k in inv.keys():
            inv[k]=inv[k]+count[k]
    print(inv)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for range in Dictionary and your code has issues with unexpected indent

```
    playerInventory = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}
    dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

    def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
        for i in addedItems:
            if i not in inventory:
                inventory.setdefault (str(i), 1)
            else:
                inventory[i] = inventory[i] + 1
        return inventory

    playerInventory = addToInventory(playerInventory, dragonLoot)
    print(playerInventory)
```

Answer (score 0):

i just got into the book and here how I solved it, seems pretty simple:

```
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']


def addToInventory(backpack, added_items):
    for i in added_items:
        if i in backpack:
            backpack[i] += 1
        else:
            count = 0
            count += 1
            backpack[i] = count

    return backpack
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
        for i in range(len(addedItems)):
            if addedItems[i] in inventory:
                inventory[addedItems[i]] = inventory[addedItems[i]] + 1
            else:
                inventory.setdefault(addedItems[i],1)
        return inventory                
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: I looped through the dragonLoot (list) and checked if the list element present in the dictionary we increased the value by 1 else if the value isn't present in the dictionary then we called dictionary's setdefault() method to add the element in the dictionary.

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me- but please add your explanation in your answer so people learning Python including OP know _why_ your answer works.

Comment: I appreciate you suggestion, will keep in mind next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
# inventory.py
# stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v) + ' ' + k)
        item_total += v
    
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        #copy() is for to avoid RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
        for k, v in inventory.copy().items():  
            if k == i:
                inventory[k] = v + 1
            if i not in inventory.keys():
                inventory[i] = 1
                    
    return inventory
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
# displayInventory(stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I figured it out. wanted to share since is the first one I did without help. hope it helps and all feedback is welcome.

`

```
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = {'gold coin':42, 'rope': 1}

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for loot in addedItems:
        inventory.setdefault(loot, 0)
        for k, v in inventory.items():
            if loot == k:
                inventory[loot] = v + 1

def displayInventory(inventory):
    totalItems = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(str(v) + '---' + str(k))
        totalItems += v
    print('Total number of items: '+ str(totalItems))
  
addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)  
displayInventory(inv)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it. I think this is a clean solution for the addToInventory() function. What do you think? Or did i missed something?

```
PlayerInventory = {"gold coin": 42, "rope": 1}
dragonLoot = ["gold coin", "dagger", "gold coin", "gold coin", "ruby"]


def displayInventory(inventory):  # Displays the Inventory
    print("Inventory:")
    cnt = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(k + " : " + str(v))
        cnt += v
    print(f"Total number of items: {cnt}")


def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):  # Add items to the provided inventory
    for item in addedItems:  # Loops trough the provided list.
        inventory.setdefault(item, 0)  # Checks if the key exists. If not, adds it with a value of 0.
        inventory[item] += 1  # Adds 1 to the value.
    return inventory  # returns the complete Dictionary


PlayerInventory = addToInventory(PlayerInventory, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(PlayerInventory)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def add(inventory,items):
    for j in items:

        for i ,k in inventory.copy().items():
            if i==j:
                inventory[i]=k+1
            else:
                inventory.setdefault(j,1)                   
    print(inventory)            

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
add(inv,dragonLoot)
```

I think this will be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
dl = (dict(Counter(dragonLoot)))


    def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
            for key, v in addedItems.items():
                    if key not in inventory:
                            inventory.setdefault(key, 1)
                    elif key in inventory:
                            inventory[key] = inventory[key] + v
            return inventory
    addToInventory(inv,dl)
    print(inv)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to note about this exercise is that it uses the function of the previous exercise and the output given on that exercise contains plural forms of items in inventory depending on the number of items so here is my version of the two exercises which follow the rules I use the inflect module for converting words to plural from Here Is The Code:

```
import inflect        #for plural forms of items in inventory
p = inflect.engine()
stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}

def displayInventory(inventory):      #this is the previous exercise as we need this function to do this exercise
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        if v > 1: #'v' is huch of given item there is
            key = p.plural(k) #if there is more than 1 of the given item 'k' converts it into plural form
        else:
            key = k #if there is only 1 of the item then no need for plural form
        print('' + str(v) + ' ' + key ) #prints the number of items + the item name example: 12 torches or 1 ruby
        item_total += v #v is added to item_total

    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1} 
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']


def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for k in addedItems: #loops over the valus in the list addedItems which is dragonLoot in this case
        if k in inventory.keys(): #if the current value of k is in the keys of inventory which is inv in this case the following  code is executed this means that the dragons loot has the item 'k'
            inventory[k] += 1 # 1 is added to the the key value of 'k' this means that the user got 1 more of the loot item
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(k, 1) # if k is not in the inventory then k is added to it and the value is set to 1
    return inventory #then the edited inventory dict is returned 


inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot) # the  function is called on inv and dragonLoot
displayInventory(inv) #the displayInventory fuction is called on inv dict
```

I hope this code works fine as I'm also a beginner "Thank You"

Answer (score 0):

You had several indentation problems and the print of the `displayinventory` function

Compare with this:

```py
def addtoinventory(inventory,lootlist):
    for i in range(len(lootlist)):
        if lootlist[i] in inventory:
            inventory[lootlist[i]] = inventory[lootlist[i]] + 1
        else:
            inventory.setdefault(lootlist[i],1)

    return inventory


def displayinventory(inventory):
    total_items = 0

    for k,v in inventory.items():
        # Change this line
        # print(k + ' : ' + str(v))
        print('%d %s' % (v,k))
        # Or print(v,k)
        # Or print(f'{v} {k}')

        total_items = total_items + v

    print("Total number of items: " + str(total_items))


inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addtoinventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayinventory(inv)
```

Additionally, I leave you my solution to that exercise:

```
def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print('%s %s' % (v,k))
        item_total += v
    print("Total number of items: %s" % item_total)

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for k in addedItems:
        inventory.setdefault(k,0)
        inventory[k] += 1
    return inventory

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

**Output:**

```
Inventory:
45 gold coin
1 rope
1 dagger
1 ruby
Total number of items: 48
```

Answer (score -1):

```
items={'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}

def displayInventory(*inventory):
    total_items = 0
    for i, j in items.items():
        print(j, i)
        total_items += j
    print("Total number of items: " + str(total_items))

displayInventory()
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to what was wrong and what need to be changed

Comment: I haven't said that there is anything wrong with the code. Usually, you'd want to give the UP some explanatory context about why this is the solution and help them learn further